# google-cloud-sdk - This account has no projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-shell

When I accessed the project of a company that is a member from the Cloud SDK in the Gsuite account, it returned "This account has no projects." Logging in with the browser, I can log in to the company's project without problems.

How can we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to open the Shell from the gcloud console? or from where are you trying to open it?

if you run `$ gcloud projects list` you should be able to check what projects your account have access.

If you already have the name of the project, you can just run `$ gcloud config set project <NAME-PROJECT>`

You can check about the commands [gcloud projects](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/) and [gcloud config](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/) on the official documentation as well.